# IIS10 shows blank pages for all sites

Tags: iis

Everything was working properly till yesterday when all our sites under IIS10 stopped working.
They show all a blank page.
DNS are OK
Sites configurations are the same of before
Commons HTTP module is installed
If I check html on browser, it's blank
I restarted IIS and also the server several times.
I saw that there were wndows updates to do. I installed them ad then one of the sites started working again (the only when where I had only a web.config that did a rewrite rule
All other sites continue to have a blank page.
I tried to create a new site with only an index.html page with "OK" inside. Always blank page

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: To investigate, people need direct access to this machine to carefully review IIS/networking configuration, and you can see that's impossible for a platform like Stack Overflow. If you need emergency support, open a support case with Microsoft via https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: I solved uninstalling and installing everything again

Comment: If you solved the question yourself without help from an answer, please post an answer yourself describing the solution, and then accept it so that future readers can learn from you.